# Declaring extern var in H file vs *only* defining it in C file

Tags: c, extern

So I've been messing around with the `extern` keyword a bit to get a better sense of what it does.

I have for example the following files:

one.h

```
#ifndef ONE_H
#define ONE_H

extern unsigned global_var;

#endif
```

one.c

```
#include "one.h"

unsigned global_var = 10;
```

two.h

```
#ifndef TWO_H
#define TWO_H

void print();

#endif
```

two.c

```
#include "one.h"
#include "two.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void print() {
  frprintf(stdout, "%u\n", global_var);
}
```

main.c

```
#include "two.h"

int main() {
  print();
  return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine and outputs: 10. As expected.

Now, if I change

one.h

```
#ifndef ONE_H
#define ONE_H

// extern unsigned global_var;

#endif
```

to be essentially empty, and

two.c

```
#include "one.h"
#include "two.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void print() {
  extern unsigned global_var;
  frprintf(stdout, "%u\n", global_var);
}
```

the behavior is exactly the same. That is, my program still compiles without warnings and outputs: 10.

So, my question is: what exactly is the difference in doing setting up a global variable one way or the other? Is one way correct and the other not?

Thanks,

PS. This was compiled using `gcc -Wall`, in case that's relevant.

Comment: Two things:  1) Think of headers of just being literally pasted into your C files before compiling, because that's exactly what happens  2) think of `extern <var decl>`  as being analogous to a forward decl of a function - you declare it but do not define it.

Comment: To literally answer your question, the only difference is that by /convention/ (hey, you can #include any file whatsoever) headers are written so as to be OK to include in multiple `.c` without causing problems.   So if you're going to need the extern var decl in lots of places, prefer to put it in a header.

Comment: The difference is that if you don't `extern` the variable in `h` file, each `c` file requiring it will need to do it by itself. It is error-prone (wrong type?) and tedious. Moreover, the writers of these files should *know* they should `extern` it. If you do it in your `h` file, the only thing to be done to the user is to include it.